# Simple WHERE clause for column name 'User ID'?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am not able to run a simple select query with a `where` clause.
I am using MySQL and have a column `User ID`.

The problem is with the column name made of two words.

```
select * from user where 'User ID' = "xyz"
```

A usual query like the next one runs fine as expected:

```
select * from user where email = 'xyz'
```

How can I write a condition on the `User ID` column?

Comment: In Standard SQL, you use double quotes around names to indicate that they are (delimited) identifiers, and case-sensitive.  In MS SQL Server, you use square brackets around the names; in MySQL, you use back-ticks around the names.  Single quotes indicate strings in all SQL DBMS.  Often, double quotes are also allowed as strings, which leads to the various alternative notations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No way to rename this column ?
You can try with backticks around the column name in your query :

```
select * from user where `User ID` = 'xyz';
```

Comment: thanks ..i just learnt today that such a character exists on our standard keyboard.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
SELECT u.* 
FROM   `user` u
WHERE  u.`User ID` = 'xyz';
```

But in general, try not to use such column names.

Using backticks to qualify the table and/or column names is also useful if you have names that conflict with MySQL keywords, e.g. `user`.

Answer (score 1):

Like [Jonathan Leffler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15168/jonathan-leffler) pointed, if you are in MS SQL Server you can try:

```
select * from user where [User ID] = "xyz"
```

or in MySql PHP Admin:

```
select * from user where ´User ID´ = "xyz"
```

I am not sure about MySql, but in SQL Server, even "login" or "user" that are some reserved words, they are functional in queries normally. Despite, I think is better not to use that.

I hope this can help you or another one. Hugs.

Ref.: 
1. [Meaning of square brackets [] in MS-SQL table designer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9917196/meaning-of-square-brackets-in-ms-sql-table-designer) 
2. [When to use single quotes, double quotes, and backticks in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks)

Answer (score -1):

I think user is a reserved word...

Try:

```
SELECT *
FROM `user`
WHERE `email` = 'xyz';
```